# rbenv-vars not taking the values to system env vars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv, rbenv-vars

I am using rbenv-vars as I have done many times to make available RAILS_MASTER_KEY in the env vars.

I have added the line to .rbenv-vars in project folder

```
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=XXXXX
```

I check with command **rbenv vars**, and it shows in the shell it's been added correcty

```
#-> export RAILS_MASTER_KEY='XXXXX'
```

But then my application fails to initialize because it doesn't find RAILS_MASTER_KEY, and checking with printenv, it isn't loaded.

What's going on?